# Bushes...will these grow back? Did I ruin them?

Tags: shrubs

Did I ruin these bushes? Will they grow back or should I take them out? Thanks [image]

Comment: What was it that you did to them? Cut their top? Replant them?

Comment: Its impossible to tell what they are from this distance - a close up shot of the leaves on the one that's got some left would be useful. When did you cut them back?

Comment: Looks like arborvitae? The photo is a bit blurry, but the leftmost looks like thuja. And was this a whole group, with the one round the corner of the porch belonging to the ensemble?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it is on the north side of your home.  Are these YEWS?  No matter, I think that whatever they are they should be fine.  Yews would be super as they are the only conifer that thrives in shade.

From now on when you prune shrubs ALWAYS make sure the *base is wider than the top.*  And one only does less than 1/3 of the plant at a time.  Don't know how big these were but if you were able to walk to your front door they couldn't have been 2/3 bigger?

The top most shrub looks healthiest, what was the condition of the lower shrubs and you HAVE to send closeups so we know what shrub you are dealing with.  The lower shrubs also have less light because of your cherry tree.

This area is screaming for a bit of terracing for the health of your foundation planting as well as visually.  Some very simple DIY ways to explain that are inexpensive and would make a big difference in the value of your home and 'curb appeal'...a great next question.

If these aren't yews we can suggest far better, shade loving hedges to replace these.  Doesn't have to be hard pruned hedges, soft pruned and we can teach you how to HEDGE or prune shrubs, trees.  Please send close ups of foliage, how long have these shrubs been in this location and did you plant them?

Comment: I'd guestimate "arborvitae".